# NSAttributedString not working on UITextField ios xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm having trouble changing the font and fontsize of a placeholder inside a UITextField.

```
this.emailTextField = new UITextField ();

//Not working
this.emailTextField.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString ("Email address", UIFont.FromName("Didot-Italic", 6.0f));

this.emailTextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress;
this.emailTextField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
this.emailTextField.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
this.emailTextField.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
this.emailTextField.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
this.emailTextField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

var bottomLayer = new CALayer ();
bottomLayer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
bottomLayer.BorderWidth = 1;
bottomLayer.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 29, 200, 1);

this.emailTextField.Layer.AddSublayer (bottomLayer);
this.emailTextField.Frame = new RectangleF (60, this.fbButton.Frame.Bottom + 20, 200, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use it like below. It worked me so far.

```
this.emailTextField.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString ("Email address", new UIStringAttributes{Font = UIFont.FromName("Didot-Italic", 6.0f)});
```

Comment: Not working at all...when debugging the font is still the system font and the size is 17.

Comment: Did you checked that you added your font properly? For example is it working when you set this font as the textfield's font?